# Prepend Zero to Long Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very long 1D array that I'd like to calculate the cumulative sum for and then prepend a zero at the beginning of the resultant array.

```
import numpy as np

def padded_cumsum(x):
    cum_sum_x = np.cumsum(x)  # Creating a new array here is fine

    return np.pad(cum_sum_x, (1,0), mode='constant')  # Prepend a single zero w/ pad

x = np.array(range(2**25))
print padded_cumsum(x)
```

The function `padded_cumsum` will be called billions of times with varying array lengths and so I am trying to avoid any array copying as that is expensive. Also, I **cannot** alter the original array `x` by instantiating it with extra values/NaNs at the beginning/end. Since `cum_sum_x` needs to be created anyways, I suspect that I can sneak in the zero there by doing something hacky like:

```
def padded_cumsum(x):
    cum_sum_x = np.empty(x.shape[0]+1)
    cum_sum_x[0] = 0 
    cum_sum_x[1:] = np.cumsum(x)

    return np.pad(cum_sum_x, (1,0), mode='constant')  # Prepend a single zero w/ pad
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy diff inverted operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563241/numpy-diff-inverted-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `out` keyword on a hand-allocated array.

```
out = np.empty(len(x)+pad, dtype=yourdtype)
np.cumsum(x, out=out[pad:])
out[:pad] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cumsum in place :

```
def padcumsum(x):
    csum=np.hstack((0,x)) # 3x faster than pad.
    csum.cumsum(out=csum)
    return csum
```

For performance issue, you can insall numba :

```
@numba.njit
def perf(x):
    csum=np.empty(x.size+1,x.dtype)
    csum[0]=0
    for i in range(x.size):
        csum[i+1]=csum[i]+x[i]
    return csum
```

which is two times faster than padcumsum

Comment: But presumably not any faster than Paul's answer?

Comment: about 2 time faster.

Comment: for what size array?

Answer (score 0):

## Performance benchmark

I compared a few options, mainly coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43563293/7128154). `np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()` is the fastest.

### result

[image]

x: problem size, y: computing time for 1000 runs

### code

```
import timeit
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmds = [
    'np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()',
    'np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()',
    'np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()',
    'csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])',
    ]
test_range = [1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6]
# test_range = [1e0, 1e1, 1e2]

ts = np.empty((len(cmds), len(test_range)), dtype=float)
for tt, size_float in enumerate(test_range):
    size = round(size_float)
    print('array size:', size)
    x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=size)

    n_trials = 1000
    for cc, cmd in enumerate(cmds):

        t = timeit.Timer(cmd, globals={**globals(), **locals()})
        t = t.timeit(n_trials)
        ts[cc, tt] = t
        print('time for {:d}x \"{:}\": {:.6f}'.format(n_trials, cmd, t))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
for cc, cmd in enumerate(cmds):
    ax.plot(test_range, ts[cc, :], label=cmd)
    print(cmd)
ax.legend()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

### output

```
array size: 1
time for 1000x "np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()": 0.015609
time for 1000x "np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.005469
time for 1000x "np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.002997
time for 1000x "csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])": 0.003499
array size: 10
time for 1000x "np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()": 0.018170
time for 1000x "np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.005663
time for 1000x "np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.002993
time for 1000x "csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])": 0.003511
array size: 100
time for 1000x "np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()": 0.018444
time for 1000x "np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.005621
time for 1000x "np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.003145
time for 1000x "csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])": 0.003770
array size: 1000
time for 1000x "np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()": 0.018034
time for 1000x "np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.007816
time for 1000x "np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.005275
time for 1000x "csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])": 0.006885
array size: 10000
time for 1000x "np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()": 0.036433
time for 1000x "np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.027001
time for 1000x "np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.024336
time for 1000x "csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])": 0.034565
array size: 100000
time for 1000x "np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()": 0.228152
time for 1000x "np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.219081
time for 1000x "np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()": 0.215639
time for 1000x "csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])": 0.311723
array size: 1000000
time for 1000x "np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()": 2.693319
time for 1000x "np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()": 2.656931
time for 1000x "np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()": 2.634273
time for 1000x "csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])": 3.755322
np.r_[[0], x].cumsum()
np.hstack(([0], x)).cumsum()
np.concatenate(([0], x)).cumsum()
csp0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(x) + 1,)); np.cumsum(x, out=csp0[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
x = np.roll(x.cumsum(), 1)
x[0] = 0
```

Using the benchmark script in Markus' answer, I find that its performance is between np.r_ and np.hstack. But this seems the fastest option if you are using PyTorch rather than Numpy.