# Renumber a sequence to remove gaps, but keep identical numbers

Tags: python, list, numpy

Assume an unordered list of numbers, with duplicates being allowed. I want to patch all gaps or sudden jumps in it. Some examples:

```py
def renum(arr):
    # magic happens here
    pass

renum(np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]))  # already in correct shape
> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

renum(np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]))  # A jump between 2 and 4
> [1,1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]

renum(np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2]))  # A forward and backward jump
> [1,1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Finding gaps is easy, but I have a hard time when trying to renumber gaps followed by the same number multiple times when processing the sequence elementwise. I.e the attempt below fails because numbers can occur many times:

```py
def renum(arr):
    new_arr = np.zeros(len(arr))
    prev_num = new_arr[0]
    for idx, num in enumerate(arr):
        diff = num - prev_num
        if diff == 0 or diff == 1:
            new_arr[idx] = num
        else:
            new_arr[idx] = prev_num + 1
        prev_num = new_arr[idx]
    return new_arr

renum(np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]))
> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]  # should actually be [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Also I think this implementation is not very efficient..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
def renum(input_array):
    diff = np.diff(input_array)
    diff[diff != 0] = 1
    return np.hstack((input_array[0], diff)).cumsum()
```

If I understood correctly, you want the differences between your values to be 0 if they are 0 in the original array. If they are non-zero, you want them to be 1. This happens in the first two lines. Now, you can use the first original element and the newly created differences to create a new array as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43563293/12182316).