# Get back original prediction from logged and differenced time-series data in python

Tags: python, logging, forecasting, arima

I am doing time-series forecasting to predict future orders. Since the data was non-stationary I did log and first-differencing. then I trained the Arima Model using the order values I got from auto_arima by passing the log-differenced data. I used last 30 days for testing and rest for training. I am getting the predicted values in the logged and differenced format. also I predicted for next 30 days which is not present in the dataset which give prediction in same format. How to get back the original data in both the cases since I don't have the data of future 30 days.

[image: logging]
[image: differencing]

[image: Prediction for testing data]

[image: Prediction for future]

Comment: please no images of code

Answer (score 4):

This can be done conveniently using numpy. The reverse operation involves taking the `cumsum()` and then the `exp()`.

You can do:
Algorithm reference [courtesy @Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563241/numpy-diff-inverted-operation/43563293#43563293)

```
series = df["Number of Bookings"]
new_series = np.log(series).diff()
# getting only the value of zeroth index since the diff() operation looses first value.
new_series.iloc[0] = np.log(series.iloc[0])
result = np.exp(new_series.cumsum())
```

Comment: what should be the 0th value for the predicted series, if I take the starting value of test data then rmse is very large compared to the previous(without reversing log-transform) results.

Comment: The zeroth index of the predicted output. Suppose you get `ypred=[1,2,3,4,5]`, then these are the log transformed and differenced data. So take `ypred[0]` in a temp variable `temp=ypred[0]` then do the `cumsum()` and `exp()` which are inverse operations.

Comment: Now after getting the `temp value` is the transformed value. I think you can do `cumsum()` like `np.concatenate((0, temp)).cumsum()` since temp itself is the first value and then take `exp()` of the result.

Comment: If we look at statistical software in general, the 0th value should be "missing value". You should remove the 0th value in the fitted value and in the original data when plotting or calculating the RMSE unless RMSE would be bigger than it should be.